# JPA ManyToMany: Adding existing object to another object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I am using JPA and wanted to figure out how the many-to-many relationship. Let's say I have a "Store" and a "Customer". These have a many to many relationship.

So my understanding is, a Store can have many Customers, and Customer can be associated with many Stores. So what I wanted to do is create two Stores and several customers. Then I wanted to have the same customer be a part of Store 1 and Store 2. However, when I saved Store 1 with the customer, and then took that same customer and associated it with Store 2 (let's say the customers shops at both stores), I get this error message: detached entity passed to persist.

Not sure how to resolve this. Any help and comments are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
@Entity
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }
    public void setCustomers(List<Customer> customers) {
        this.customers = customers;
    }
    public Store() {
    }   
    public Store(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }   
    public Long getId() {
       return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    } 
    public Store addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
        return this;
    }
}

@Entity 
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

```
@Entity  
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    public Item() { }

    public Item(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Item() {
    }   
    public Item(String name, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
   }    
   public String getName() {
        return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
   }
   public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
   }
   public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
   }
}
```

This is the driver code using Spring Boot:
    Store safeway = new Store("Safeway4");

```
safeway.addItem(new Item("Fuji Apple", new BigDecimal(1)));
safeway.addItem(new Item("Black Grapes", new BigDecimal(2)));
safeway.addItem(new Item("Cheese Pizza", new BigDecimal(10)));

Store bestBuy = new Store("Best Buy4");
bestBuy.addItem(new Item("55 inch TV", new BigDecimal(550)));
bestBuy.addItem(new Item("Bluray Player", new BigDecimal(85)));
bestBuy.addItem(new Item("Nikon SLR", new BigDecimal(1500)));

Customer elf = new Customer();
elf.setName("Elf");
Customer neo = new Customer();
neo.setName("Neo");
safeway.getCustomers().add(elf);
safeway.getCustomers().add(neo);

Customer yoda = new Customer();
yoda.setName("Yoda");
Customer crazy = new Customer();
crazy.setName("Crazy"); 
bestBuy.getCustomers().add(yoda);
bestBuy.getCustomers().add(crazy);

log.debug("adding neo to best buy");           
bestBuy.getCustomers().add(neo); // Adding Neo to both stores! 

log.debug("saving safeway 1");
storeRepository.save(safeway); 
log.debug("saving safeway 1 done");

log.debug("saving bestBuy 1");
storeRepository.save(bestBuy); // error happens here <----------- 
log.debug("saving bestBuy 1 done");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `CascadeType.ALL`, you'll avoid this problem.

Logically, a `Customer` can exist without ever being associated to any `Store`.  That means the lifecycle of a `Customer` should be independent of that of a `Store` entity, thus cascading any operation for a `Customer` from `Store` is wrong.

You save your `Customer` instances separately, associate the saved instances with the appropriate `Store` and then save it separately.

Comment: Thank you Naros! Your answer fixed the problem.